# How many GPUs can these deep learning algorithms be parallelized across (batch parallelization)?

Tags: deep-learning, deep-neural-networks

The deep learning algorithms I would to know the limits of are:

1. CNTK
2. Caffe
3. TensorFlow
4. Torch7
5. Theano

For example: I've heard TensorFlow is near impossible to parallelize on 8 GPUs and above. So, in this case, the limit would be 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this answer refers solely to TensorFlow, as my knowledge of the remaining frameworks is limited.*

Where did you hear that TensorFlow is near impossible to parallelize on more than 8 GPUs? With a large enough network, any number of GPUs can be used to speed-up training, as shown in the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu). This snippet of code introduces the multiplication of 2 constants in 2 separate GPUs. This allows you to run the graph on both simultaneously.

```
for d in ['/gpu:2', '/gpu:3']:
    with tf.device(d):
        a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3])
        b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2])
        c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))
```

**Even if there were some sort of limit on how many GPUs TensorFlow can use per process, TF can be [distributed](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) across processes and machines.** Asynchronous algorithms (like [A3C](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783)) can be spread across, for example, 16 machines (what I am doing in my laboratory), where each machine uses its resources (in my case, I use CPU, but the change to a GPU would be trivial).

With a complex enough network and a well implemented solution, you can take advantage of any hardware resources you have.

Comment: Also, in order to be in competition with tensor flow, most other deep learning architectures support this (or have plans to) as well.

Answer (score 2):

As an example for Caffee: Facebook parallelized the training of a 
[Res-Net CNN over 256 GPUs](https://research.fb.com/publications/imagenet1kin1h/)